# Solving a matrix equation in which the coefficient matrix is not diagonally dominant using Gauss-Seidel

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-equations

I have to solve the following matrix equation using Gauss Seidel :

$\begin{bmatrix}25 & 5 & 1\\64 & 8 & 1\\144&12&1 \end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{bmatrix}$= $\begin{bmatrix}106.8\\177.2\\279.2 \end{bmatrix}$

The coefficient matrix isn't diagonally dominant and it cannot be transformed into one. The solution doesn't converge. Even using under-relaxation doesn't help. Does this mean that iterative procedures cannot be used to solve this matrix equation?

Answer (score 1):

From [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method): the convergence properties of the Gauss–Seidel method are dependent on the matrix $A$. Namely, the procedure is known to converge if either:

- $A$ is symmetric positive-definite, or
- $A$ is strictly or irreducibly diagonally dominant.

**The Gauss–Seidel method sometimes converges even if these conditions are not satisfied.**

If we do the best we can with putting the matrix in DD form (the original matrix fails to converge), we have

$$\begin{bmatrix}144&12&1\\64 & 8 & 1\\25 & 5 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}279.2\\177.2\\106.8 \end{bmatrix}$$

Starting from an initial point of $(1,1,0)$, after $140$ iterations, we converge to:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0.290476\\19.6905\\1.08572 \end{bmatrix}$$

Using a different solver, we get

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0.2904761904761902 \\
 19.6904761904762 \\
 1.085714285714253\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Note: you can also use [*Gaussian Elimination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) on the original matrix to verify this result.

As to your original question, sometimes we can use these iterative solvers even when we cannot satisfy all of the conditions listed earlier.